# How to render facebook comment plugin after ajax?

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-comments

in header

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="my id"/> 
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="my api"/>
```

And in body

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=my api";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

In html

```
<div id="facebook">
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?= $this->productLink ?>" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
    </div>
```

I find problem-i load my web page with ajax and that facebook code don't work with ajax.
How render my facebook comments after ajax? Execute that function?

Comment: I add <script type="text/javascript">
       FB.XFBML.parse();
</script>

in my ajax code and all work now!

Answer (score 21):

Add the following javascript code just below the ajax for showing facebook comment plugin.

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Refer:http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: I have new problem-comments on my web page not separated! If i add comment in one comment box-that comment will be added to all comment box! I add xid, but that don't work

Comment: Provide different 'data-href' url for each comment box.